# Rendering 2D barcode bitmaps

Tags: bitmap, barcode

I have an application that processes SVG messages sent from a customer's host. Embedded in that message are several images, one of which is a 2D (PDF-417) barcode. I have a main canvas for rendering all the various elements contained in the SVG message, this includes text and some other imagery, or icons. Everything works great except when it comes to rendering the 2D barcode. The 2D barcode is getting rendered to the canvas and looks really clean and sharp however no barcode reader can read the barcode. If I save the original barcode downloaded from the host I can scan it with any reader. Not only that I can scale it, rotate it, do almost anything to it, I just can scan the final barcode rendered to the main canvas.

I'm drawing the barcode bitmap to the main canvas with Graphics.DrawImage.

```
_innerGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
_innerGraphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, srcRect, graphicsUnit);
```

Close examination of the original bitmap and the image rendered to the main canvas does show some differences, but not being a 2D barcode expert and not have the very expensive barcode analyzer tool makes it difficult to impossible to determine exactly what is wrong.

The diffculty of 2D (PDF417) barcodes is that the image must be exact or the BCR (barcode reader) will not be able to scan the image.

*********** Added content ******
Yes, I saw that. And for the most part I agree with you. However, by doing a lot of reading, experimenting and discussing the problem with another engineer here I/we came up with the following 3 options that we applied to the Graphics object property "InterpolationMode.

// good - innerGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

// GOOD            _innerGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

_innerGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

I left it set at InterpolationMode.High for the time being for testing purposes. The image rendered scans very well now. The confusing item is the rendered image that now works still has those unequal lines you pointed out along with a few other items that I would have guessed should have made it fail.

Additional information:
I few more items you should know. The main canvas that the SVG engine is rendering to via the C# Graphics object has a pixel format of Format32bppArgb. The bitmap containing the barcode that's being downloaded from the customer's WEB site is Format24bppRgb. The barcode image is being rendered to the main canvas via Graphics.DrawImage().
I think the Graphics object is doing its best to morph the 24bppRgb format into the 32bppArgb format causing the distortion. If I just print the original 24 bit bitmap image it creates a beautiful bitmap. It looks like a sharp 1 bit monochrome image. 
I’m kind of at a loss as to what is the exact/correct was to get this barcode bitmap rendered onto the main drawing canvas. I’ve got to credit my success so far to more or less guess work.

If possible I will attempt to attach the 2 bitmaps for viewing.

Bad image: [Bad final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydmjy.png)
Good image: [Good image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBkMj.png)

Can anyone please help?

9/1/2017 - Update
This morning I extrapolated the core pieces of the code out of the SVG library needed for rendering that 2D barcode. I was somewhat successful in recreating the problem. Next I started adjusting some of the math and values  to get an understand of how the different function points were effecting the rendering of the barcode to the main canvas. I can now render that 2D barcode in just about any size I want ( WITHIN REASON ) and render a beautiful perfect 2D barcode.
Some of the adjustments I'm not quite sure I understand just yet, but what was once fuzzy and totally confusing is slowly starting to come into focus. Starting to understand what's going on. In short it's the source and destination rectangle calculations when rendering to the main canvas.
After much testing and experimenting I'm pretty sure the problem has boiled down to scaling. That original bitmap I sent you outputorig.bmp size is 808 x 175. This is how I receive it from the customer's host. I have no control over it's size. This bitmap must be rendered into a rectangle on the main canvas 245 x 94. That's about 30% of it's original size. I can shrink it to some degree with success using a variety of scaling routines I have found on the WEB. I've been able to shrink it down to about 60% of it's original size and still be able to scan the barcode. I go much beyond that and it becomes unscannable.
Any ideas anyone?

Thanks
Al Harper

Comment: Looks like a horizontal scaling issue. Bar widths are not consistent in the bad image. For example, in the lowermost, leftmost element, the two thinnest bars should be exactly the same width. In the good image they are, in the bad image they are not. Is the SVG trying to draw each element as a set of black or white rectangles?

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to give reply so added more content in main post.

Comment: Are you having difficulty scanning off the screen or a printed copy? Is there a reason you can't use Format1bppIndexed?

Comment: Just noticed your closing question. The SVG rendering DLL controls the pixel format. The main canvas is 32 bit ARgb. I've tried a half dozen conversion routines found on web to convert to mono but the end result was worse.